# JAXB, more than one namespace per element in POJOs to unmarshal XML

Tags: java, xml, parsing, xsd, jaxb

How can I accept different versions of `namesspaces` to `unmarshal`? I have many classes generated using JAXB. I want to unmarshal to get information from the XMLs. The problem is that the xmls have different `xmlns` versions.

I will make a simple example as the classes I have are too long.

Having the class:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = { "attribute1"})
    @XmlRootElement(name = "myClass", namespace = "http://www.test.com/xml-schema/MYC/1.0")
    public class myClass {

        @XmlElement(name = "attribute_1", namespace = "http://www.test.com/xml-schema/MYC/1.0", required = true)
        protected String attribute1;

        @XmlElement(name = "attribute_2", namespace = "http://www.test.com/xml-schema/MYC/1.0")
        protected String attribute2;
    }
```

I would like to accept not only a `XML` with the `xmlns` like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<Reha xmlns="http://www.test.com/xml-schema/MYC/1.0"
```

But as well `xmlns` like:

```
http://www.test.com/xml-schema/MYC/1.2
http://www.test.com/xml-schema/MYC/1.5
http://www.test.com/xml-schema/MYC/1.8
http://www.test.com/xml-schema/MYC/2.9
```

Having in mind I have other classes with other namesspaces, with the same problem (different versions in the namesspace)

I have read different posts but it is not clear for me. How could I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After giving a deeper thought and understanding the user case.

In the case that a schema has different versions, it means that the structure of the `XML` changes, and that means that we will need two different classes to represent two different namespaces' versions, for example for the two different namespaces:

```
http://www.test.com/xml-schema/MYC/1.2
http://www.test.com/xml-schema/MYC/1.5
```